# Array.length is returning undefined when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an array that returns undefined when I check the length (array.length) only the page is refreshed.

If I open my local environment in a new tab in chrome, everything works fine, and I get the length of the array. Only after refreshing the page once, the page crashes and I get the following error: 
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

I am using React, React's Context API (I am getting the array from the context provider) and Nextjs for the project. I have a feeling this issue connected with SSR, but I'm not entirely sure.

Here is the relevant code connected with the problem.

**Context Provider**

```
export function CartProvider(props) {
    let initializeState;
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        initializeState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'));
        if (initializeState === null) {
            initializeState = [];
        }
    }

    // Sets the cart
    const [ cart, setCart ] = useState(initializeState);
    return (
        <CartContext.Provider
            value={{ cart, setCart, checkCart, addItem, deleteItem, quantityIncrease, quantityDecrease }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

And this is the code that is consuming the Context Provider

**Cart.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from 'react';
import ShoppingCart from '../components/ShoppingCart';
import { CartContext } from '../contexts/CartContext';
const cart = () => {
    const { cart } = useContext(CartContext);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {cart.length !== 0 ? (
                <ShoppingCart />
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <h1>Your cart is empty</h1>
                </div>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default cart;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `.length` returns `undefined` then it's not an array.

Comment: I've checked the array using Array.isArray(cart) and it returns array. It's when the page is refreshed I get the error.

Comment: Okay, so what is your question then? After the page is refreshed it's not an array but something else, hence its `.length` returns `undefined`.

Comment: When I simply console.log(cart), without checking the length, the page it always returns [ ], which is an array. This happens regardless of whether or not I refresh the page.

Comment: show this `console.log(cart, typeof cart, Array.isArray(cart), cart.length)`

Comment: I get the following when I run console.log(cart, typeof cart, Array.isArray(cart), cart.length).

cart = Array(0);  typeof = "object";  Array.isArray = true; cart.length = 0

Comment: So, it works fine then, `cart.length` is not `undefined`. The problem is solved?

Comment: Not quite. Then I refreshed the page and got the same error I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: Why did you post the requested `console.log` for the **WORKING PAGE**? What's the requested `console.log` output for the **BROKEN PAGE**?

Comment: My mistake. I had to open a new tab to get the whole thing working again. For the broken page I get the same error.

Comment: What _same_ error? What is the output for the requested `console.log` ?

Comment: I get this error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: Then the value is `undefined`, the error says it all. So `cart === undefined` in your code.

Comment: That makes sense. I am having a problem figuring out why that is. Do you have any input as to how to fix the error? I am trying to determine if the cart is empty. This error happens even if the array is populated.

Comment: Show your `../contexts/CartContext`, it's the react context that does not have the data you want

Comment: That information is provided under Context Provider in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your bug related to SSR.

If you run the code with SSR, the initializeState will receive undefined.
But initializeState should be Array as you expected.

So, I suggest you change your code:

```js
// Change
    let initializeState;
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        initializeState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'));
        if (initializeState === null) {
            initializeState = [];
        }
    }

// To
    let initializeState = [];
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && sessionStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        initializeState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'));
    }
```

You can make the code safer by catching the error while calling JSON.parse. But, if you make sure `sessionStorage.getItem('cart')` is always correct, you can keep this code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of asynchronicity. The variable is not initialized at the time of evaluation and that is how you get the:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Try applying the guard pattern when you consume the provider like so:

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from 'react';
import ShoppingCart from '../components/ShoppingCart';
import { CartContext } from '../contexts/CartContext';
const cart = () => {
    const { cart } = useContext(CartContext);

    return (
        <Fragment>
            {(cart && (cart.length !== 0)) ? (
                <ShoppingCart />
            ) : (
                <div>
                    <h1>Your cart is empty</h1>
                </div>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default cart;
```

Quick explainer:

```
cart && (cart.length !== 0)
```

translates to:

> WHEN symbol "cart" evaluates to a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value,
>
> THEN return the result of the expression "cart.length !== 0",
>
> ELSE return false

This way you "guard" unsafe code at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, that didn't seem to do the trick. I still get TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined when I run that code.

Comment: @RogyBear that is strange! Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/s3de1j8o/10/